# iOS Swift manipulate/parse string

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure how to do this in iOS Swift

```
let test = "fnfsjflsjlkdkfj?v=904kg4"
// search test for ?v= and store everything after ?v= into a new string
let newString = "904kg4"
```

I want everything after ?v= into a new string, is this possible? if so, how can I accomplish this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rangeOfString` to find the range of `?v=` and then use `substringFromIndex` to get the rest of the string:

```
let test = "fnfsjflsjlkdkfj?v=904kg4"
if let range = test.rangeOfString("?v=") {
    let newString = test.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
}
```

Comment: You can also use the simple method without options.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBoboc! Updated.